# Password Validation using hibernate bean validation

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am trying to validate user input password against set of rules and here are those rules.

1. Minimum 6 and Maximum 8 Character.
2. Atleast 1 number
3. Atleast 1 alphabet in capitals.
4. No Special char allowed

this is what i have done so far in my bean class

```
@NotNull(message = "{register.pwd.invalid}")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 8, message = "{register.pwd.invalid}")
    public String getPwd()
    {
        return pwd;
    }
```

I believe for the rest part i have to use regExp but not sure what regular expression i need to have, this is what i came up

```
^.*(?=.{6,8})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

i am not sure about the expression as i am not good in regExp,can any one help me to point in correcting the regExp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}$
```

Don't use `.*` at the start (it would sabotage the length check) and move the length check to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first `.*` and anchor the char limit, eg:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}$
```